# Mechanism and type of polymerization of chloroethene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, polymers

Ethene reacts with hydrogen chloride to form a monomer used in the production of a polymer. This monomer is chloroethene.

How is the polymer formed from the monomer?
Is this an addition or a condensation polymerization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it wrong - monomer is chloroethene ([vinyl chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_chloride)) and nothing is eliminated in [addition polymerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-growth_polymerization) in contrary to [polycondensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_polymer). This monomer is made via addition of chlorine molecule to ethene and elimination of hydrogen chloride. Alternative methods are addition of hydrogen chloride to acetylene or [oxychlorination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogenation#Oxychlorination) - in this reaction $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{O2}$ react with ethylene to form the monomer and water.

Comment: But how is a chlorine molecule added?

Comment: Huh? Simple electrophilic addition reaction.